# Parse JSONArray data Exception from PHP script

Tags: php, android, json

I got the Error message in Android below, it is send by PHP server implemet it as JSON array:

```
03-20 15:19:17.479: D/requestWorldRecords()(353): org.json.JSONException: Value {"Error":"No Result!"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

The PHP script is as below:

```
$data = array('Error' => "No Result!");  
print_r(urlencode(json_encode($data)));
```

Can any body correct me where I was wrong , thanks for the help !

Comment: How you use Json in your java code ? Can you put that part ?

Comment: Post code related to the issue. It seems you are trying to convert JSonObject to JSonArray.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. The code for Parsing is:      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: print json_encode($data); this will work for any kind of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a json object, not an array. try

> String jsoncontent = ...
>
> JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsoncontent);

Comment: Thaksfor timosch help ! However, there still had the syntax error prompted. I could not find the package to be importted for my eclipse envionment for the method of json_encode() or json_decode(). Would you correct me !

Comment: Hello,... I am not quite sure whether it is right way or not. I used JSONArray in Android side, (...JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);...) to convert the data posted from mysql database and it wroks without problem. However, the error prompted while the data content is build manually.

Comment: The php script  for collecting data is as: ...... $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
  if (empty($result))
  {         
      $data = array('Error' => "No Result!");  
    print_r(urlencode(json_encode($data)));
    return;
  }
 
 //Fetech every line of result
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
    $output[]=$row;
 }
 print_r(urlencode(json_encode($output))); ..........